# ¿como hacer que ireport genere nada mas una tabla?

Tags: java, java-swing, ireport

el problemas de que mi ireport e que me genera 4 o 5 tablas y a la hora de que se llena con un jQuery se me agranda hasta 15 paginas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el QUERY que utilizo junto con un parámetro que toma el valor de otro parámetro que se llena de otro query pero este si me funciona y es solo 1

```
SELECT idRegistroCarnet,nombresw,versionSw FROM repswequip INNER JOIN registrocarnet USING (idRegistroCarnet)  INNER JOIN software USING (idSoftware)where idRegistroCarnet = $P{idDataset}
```

y aquí esta el JavaScript de la tabla por si acaso

```
<detail>
    <band height="117" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="105" y="16" width="360" height="80" uuid="89865b72-cb15-44cf-812a-f76b07f707e1"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="reportesw" uuid="a535535a-ea28-4760-a65b-424b9daeb02a">
                    <datasetParameter name="idDataset">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{idRegistroCarnett}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="bd859ea7-af56-4aba-8251-e410ca85a4b4">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="a51ded26-d90b-46a3-98d7-438ae241e8f5"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                <font fontName="Comic Sans MS" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Registro Carnet]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="c300bd78-bd39-4ea8-a6cb-b6bfd86f62aa"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idRegistroCarnet}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="133" uuid="e78df592-6be0-4af7-af1f-5015b866dc3b">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="133" height="30" uuid="069eb518-707c-4aa2-9206-caf1a776c2a9"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                <font fontName="Comic Sans MS" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Software]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="133" height="20" uuid="da54520a-97f0-4739-a3c8-65228cf3cb9d"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nombresw}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="135" uuid="09aec3f0-8c6d-414d-872c-42c5b706cbc1">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="135" height="30" uuid="937eaff8-300e-4f24-a7a4-dfdcdbf3f7eb"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                <font fontName="Comic Sans MS" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Version]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:columnFooter style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="135" height="20" uuid="245a1895-8b09-4451-a5f4-0ce6ef5f6ce7"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{versionSw}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

como soy novato no entiendo muy bien este código, yo me he estado moviendo mas por el lado grafico del ireport  en el que nada mas tengo una tabla pero aun asi me genera 4 o 5 tabla mas a la hora de compilarlo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: mmmm es que es por medio de ireport no hay codigo :(

Comment: Amistá, iReport claro que genera código. Si no me falla, uno trabaja sobre un jrxml (a través de una GUI lo más de bonita) que, al compilarse, se hace un .jasper. Tampoco sabemos qué es lo que haces con java y mucho menos, qué tiene que ver jQuery ahí (que es javascript)

Comment: ya le agrege el query que uso

Comment: Esa tabla se te está repitiendo porque la pusiste en la banda que no es y se repite por cada registro de alguna cosa o por algún criterio que no tenemos cómo saber. Sin ver la definición del reporte, complicáo